# Get database list in Npgsql

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

How can I get a list of all available `PostgreSQL` databases on a user's computer using `Npgsql` in `C#`?

Comment: Execute `select datname from pg_database;` against the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In postgreSQL there are two way to do it :

- `\l`
- `SELECT datname FROM pg_database;`

Comment: and where are using `Npgsql`?

Answer (score 0):

Using `Npgsql` You can use such code snippet:

```cs
IEnumerable<string> GetDatabaseNames()
{
    var connStrBuilder = new NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    connStrBuilder.Host = "localhost";
    connStrBuilder.Username = "theduck";
    connStrBuilder.Password = "password123";
    connStrBuilder.Database = "postgres"; // this database is always present

    using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connStrBuilder.ConnectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (var command = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datistemplate = false ORDER BY datname;", conn))
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                yield return reader.GetString(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```